# Getting values from listbox on a userform VBA (Excel)

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, userform

I want to get the values from my listbox which is on a userform.

```
Me.lb_stuff = my listbox

For i = 0 To Me.lb_stuff.ListCount
   addtoOS = foofunction(number, Me.lb_stuff.List(XX?), Me.lb_stuff.List(XX?)
Next i
```

I searched for quiet some time, but their where only tutorials for getting selected items..
Is it only possible to get selected items? that would be weird..

Thanks in advance, hope my question is clear

Comment: Tried `.List(Row, ColumnIndex)`? Check if a row is selected: `.Selected(Row)`. Row: Zero to .ListCount-1, ColumnIndex zero to ColumnCount.

Comment: for a one dimensional listbox : val(i) = ListBoxName.List(i)

Comment: Oke thanks! I found it